# Замена контента блока на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Есть такой скриптик:

```
$(function(){   
    $('.faqParagraph').hide();
    $('.faqAnchor').bind('click', function() {
        var faq = $(this).parent('.child');
        $(faq).children('.faqParagraph').slideToggle(200);
        $(faq).toggleClass('faqActive');
        return false;
    });
});

<div class="faqAnchor"><a href="#">Подробнее...</a></div>
```

Можно ли в блоке faqAnchor при открытии блока faqParagraph заменить текст "Подробнее..." на "Закрыть"?

Comment: Да, даю добро!

Comment: Для начала я бы сократил исходный код вот так:

 $(function(){   
     $('.faqParagraph').hide();
     $('.faqAnchor').click(function(){
         $(this).parent('.child').children('.faqParagraph').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('faqActive');
         return false;
     });
 });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете менять содержимое тэга "A" в момент открытия:

```
$('.faqAnchor a').html('Закрыть')
```

и обратно когда закрываете

```
$('.faqAnchor a').html('Подробнее...')
```

А так же обратите внимание на свой код

```
var faq = $(this).parent('.child');
$(faq).children('.faqParagraph').slideToggle(200);
$(faq).toggleClass('faqActive');
```

вы в переменную faq  и так получаете query объект, зачем дополнительно заворачивать его в  $()? Можно просто прописать

```
faq.toggleClass('faqActive').children('.faqParagraph').slideToggle(200);
```

**UPD**: У вас есть вклчюение и выключение класса $(faq).toggleClass('faqActive'); В зависимости от него и меняйте текст

```
$(faq).toggleClass('faqActive');
 $(faq).children('a').html($(faq).hasClass('faqActive')?'Закрыть':'Подробнее...');
```

Comment: А можно подробнее про закрыть открыть.. Я не знаю, как это внедрить)
А со вторым. Я просто что новичок. Есть вообще разница - в скобках или без? Просто в скобках визуально удобнее

Comment: кстати да, этот вариант современнее))))

Answer (score 2):

```
$(faq).children('a').html("Закрыть")
```

примерно так

ps;

```
if (isOpen) { isOpen = false; $(faq).children('a').html("Подробнее"); } else { isOpen = true; $(faq).children('a').html("Закрыть"); }
```

Comment: а обратно вернуть при закрытии?

Comment: ну использовать какойто флаг можно типа isOpen и менять его типа if (isOpen) { isOpen = false; $(faq).children('a').html("Подробнее"); } else { isOpen = true; $(faq).children('a').html("Закрыть"); }